# is there a way to run a Javascript on IE without using the developer tools

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a JavaScript injection that I created to be used in Chrome. We use it to gather statistics of a web page we are working with and compare it to known data. The script works fine with chrome. I have users set up a new bookmark, give it a name that will remind them that it is a script. and then have them load the script into the HTML field of the book mark. So that they can run the script against the webpage on a click of a link.

The problem is a new group of users want to begin using the as well script but have requested a solution for IE. Is there a similar way to run a script in IE?  I know they can enter the script in the Development Tools and run it from there but, I was hoping for a solution where they wouldn't have to manually load the script for each webpage.

Comment: IE version are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

"javascript:" links like `javascript:alert(1)` is a way run script. You can add it to favorites bar for example.

Note that you can't copy/paste it to address bar, but you have to type "javascript:" by hand.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [bookmarklet](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). And you can add them in internet explorer pretty easily, if memory serves, by providing a `javascript:` link on a page, right clicking on it in IE, and clicking "Add to favorites."

Example bookmarklet installation instructions from some random page: http://help.readability.com/customer/portal/articles/254194-how-do-i-install-the-bookmarklet-for-internet-explorer-